# no gap (space) between input elements angular

Tags: html, angular

I have square component with **selector 'app-square'**:

```
<input type="text"/>
```

I have styles for that component:

```
 input[type=text] {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      font-size: 15pt;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

And i want that there will be no gap between two app-square elements.

```
<app-square></app-square>
<app-square></app-square>
```

Now, you can notice a little gap betweet elements:

[image]

I do not want that gap between elements, how should i achieve it?

[image]

Comment: margin ? padding ?

Comment: no, i am adding one more image to clarify the problem, paddings and margin do not work

Comment: I can't see images, sorry. I just didn't see any margin or padding into your CSS.

Comment: Either use a negative `margin-left: -4px;` or set the `display` to `block` and `float` them using `float: left`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generating for you putting the every element in new lines. You can remove it by keep them in same line without white-space like following:

```
<input type="text"/><input type="text"/><input type="text"/><input type="text"/><input type="text"/><input type="text"/>
```

Or by using CSS force:

```
.clearfix::after {
    display: table;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
}
input[type=text] {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      font-size: 15pt;
      text-align: center;
      display: block;
      float: left;
      margin: 0;
      vertical-align: top;
}

<div class='clearfix'>
   <input type="text"/>
   <input type="text"/>
   <input type="text"/>
   <input type="text"/>
   <input type="text"/>
   <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is caused by the `display` property which is set as `inline-block` by default. It adds a gap between the *elements*.

So you could use a negative `margin`, or instead of `inline-block` float them.

The preferred way is floating them:

```css
.container::before,
.container::after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
}

input {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 15pt;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<input value="0" />
<input value="0" />
<input value="0" />
<input value="0" />
<input value="0" />
<input value="0" />
</div>
```

Don't forget to clear the *floating* elements using the following `css` on the `container` of the floated elements.

```
.container::before,
.container::after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
}
```